# Cache in CodeIgniter's Tank Auth Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching, tankauth

Hi I was wondering if you guys have a problem with Tank Auth. After logging in and hits back the login form still shows up. I wonder if there's a workaround for that like redirection?

Thanks,

Xxxxxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page is being cached, try something like this in your login controller to prevent it:

```
$this->output
    ->set_header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s").' GMT')
    ->set_header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0')
    ->set_header('Pragma: no-cache')
    ->set_header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```